# Play Framework 2.4 - Dependency injection to replace GlobalSettings.onStart()

Tags: java, playframework, dependency-injection, guice, playframework-2.4

I'm confused with regards to dependency injection. What I want to achieve is to replace the `GlobalSettings.onStart()` call, where I initialized some static singleton objects in 2.3, with proper dependency injection of those objects.

What I am trying to do is this:

Controller -> Model (inject an object into this model)

What I have so far is a half way measure; in the controller:

```
private static SomeObject myStaticSingletonObject = new SomeObject();

public Promise<Result> getSomeData() {
    return handleRequest(() -> new SomeDataAjaxRequest(myStaticSingletonObject));
}

public Promise<Result> handleRequest(Function0<AbstractAjaxRequest<?>> supplier) {
    Promise<AbstractAjaxRequest<?>> promise = Promise.promise(supplier);
    return promise.map(arg -> ok(arg.getResponse()));
}
```

handleRequest() is a custom method I use and isn't really related but I include it for completeness:

And in the model I just take the SomeObject as a param:

```
private final SomeObject someObject;

public SomeDataAjaxRequest(SomeObject someObject) {
    super(null);
    this.someObject = someObject;
}
```

In my build.sbt I have:

```
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

So basically my question is how should I be injecting SomeObject into my models and also how should I be creating my SomeObject object, I don't think I should be using `new SomeObject()`.

Ideally I would like to use field injection for these objects as I don't want to clutter the constructor which might actually have relevant params for the model rather than just these utility classes that contain definitions of things (SomeObject basically just loads some information from the database which currently is static throughout the lifetime of the application, but that may change).

Also it is probably worth noting that I am intending to use Guice to manage DI.

I understand that I should create a Guice DI factory and have seen the docs for this but I still am unsure how to integrate this into my play app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly create a Guice DI factory for this.

Instead, create a module and use this to configure any bindings and - importantly for you - replacements for `onStart()`.

```
import play.api.inject.Module;

public class SomeModule extends Module {
    @Override
    public Seq<Binding<?>> bindings(final Environment environment,
                                    final Configuration configuration)
    {
        return seq(bind(SomeObject.class).toSelf().eagerly());
    }
}
```

Make sure you annotate `SomeObject` with `javax.inject.Singleton` to ensure its status.  The point of `eagerly` in the module is to ensure the object is initialised as early as possible.

`SomeObject` will then be available for DI, having been invoked once; you can use the constructor to initialise whatever you need to do.

To expose this module to your application, add it to the `application.conf`:

```
play {
  modules {
    enabled += "com.example.SomeModule"
  }
}
```

In your controller, just inject the instance as you normally would:

```
public class SomeController extends Controller {
    private final SomeObject someObject;

    @Inject
    public SomeController(final SomeObject someObject) {
        this.someObject = someObject;
    }

    public Promise<Result> getSomeData() {
        return handleRequest(() -> new SomeDataAjaxRequest(someObject));
    }

    public Promise<Result> handleRequest(Function0<AbstractAjaxRequest<?>> supplier) {
        return Promise.promise(supplier)
                      .map(arg -> ok(arg.getResponse()));
    }
}
```

Comment: When I try the example code at the top of this answer in Play 2.4.2 , I get numerous compiler errors, such as "...Module must be declared abstract or implement configure()".  How could the above code have compiled?  Has Play changed that much since this post was made?  Any idea where I could find working example code of early, self binding?

Comment: I just noticed the import and superclass are wrong - I've corrected the example.

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly.  I've seen a few early binding examples. I think they're for Play 2.4.x.  Some implement Module.  Others extend AbstractModule.  Are there any important differences between these two approaches?

Comment: `Module` is Play-internal, so if you're writing a module for general consumption it doesn't force a dependency on a specific framework like Guice.  If you're writing something for internal use, you can use a framework-specific class like Guice's `AbstractModule`.  See [this](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaDependencyInjection#Play-libraries) for further info.

Comment: Thanks.  Now my module compiles! Next step is to figure out the new Play way to get environment config.  Looks like `public static final String myVar = Play.application().config().getString(...)` may be causing boot errors in one my early bind components.

Comment: Inject `Configuration`!  Otherwise, start a new question and I'll give a fuller answer.

Comment: I'm new to Play and didn't know about injectable config.  I'll follow up on your suggestion.  Thanks again:-)

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Migration24), it should help you a lot.